# Error while extracting zip file created from maven assembly plugin

Tags: zip, maven-assembly-plugin, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using maven assembly plugin to create a `zip` packaging resources from another maven module in the same project.

`Parent_project
|_module1
  |_resources
    |_templates
      |_abc.xml
|_module2
  |_resources
    |_build-config.xml`

Below is my `build-config.xml` file.

```
<assembly
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>bundle</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${basedir}/../module1/src/main/resources/templates</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <outputDirectory>/testdir</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

I'm able to copy the resources to a sub-directory named `testdir` inside the zip file's root. (I can observe this by viewing the zip file without extracting it.) But if i try to extract the zip, it gives me the below error.
`There was an error while extracting the sample.zip. "sample/testdir/abc.xml": Not a directory.`

I'm using Ubuntu 18 with maven assembly plugin version -1.1.2

Can someone please point me the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I tried for a while and observed below. Extracting through UI option causes the error. If i were to use the `unzip ./myzip.zip -d .` command, the extraction success.

But i found a workaround for this as below.

1. Create an empty directory first.

   `<fileSet> <!-- Create empty directory -->
       <outputDirectory>./templates</outputDirectory>
       <excludes>
           <exclude>**/*</exclude>
       </excludes>
   </fileSet>`
2. Copy resources to the directory.

   `<fileSet>
       <directory>${basedir}/test</directory>
       <includes>
           <include>*.xml</include>
       </includes>
       <outputDirectory>./templates</outputDirectory>
   </fileSet>`
   This method fixes the issue while extracting the zip. Cheers!